# How to achieve p2p on android

Tags: android, p2p

So I am developing a little game in which the users will try to answer the same question in real time. I thought the best way for the users communication is p2p. After 3 days searching, I found that there 3 possible solutions. 
1. XMPP. Recommended by a lot people. Unfortunately not many people in China use GTalk.
2. Jxta. Seems dead and complex.
3. SIP. It requires the user to have a SIP account.
p2p seems to be really hard on cell phones. 
My question:
Is p2p really the best solution to my problem?
If it is, what is the best way to achieve p2p connection on cell phones?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does XMPP really require a Google Talk account? As far as I know it is a standalone protocol that happens to be used by Google Talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only issue with `XMPP` is that your users don't use Google Talk you should set up a server and rely on in-band registration.

Look at these Q&A to learn [what it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411970/what-is-in-band-registration-in-xmpp) and [how you can get it in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709658/asmack-xmpp-new-user-registration)

Comment: Thanks. 
I am just developing a little game app. Maintaining a xmpp server is expensive to me. My plan is to use something like Google App Engine. I guess my only choice is to dive into jxta now.

Comment: Since you are targeting Android, why don't you leverage the fact that almost all the users also have a Google account?
I don't know how well it does fit with your needs, but you should have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

An XMPP server is easy to setup, use OpenFire. I've done this before, you have to install a java virtual machine on a server and then install OpenFIre.

To create a client application, you can based your work on the ASMACK library which is very complete.

For me, it worked but my server cann't handle OpenFire. I just have a dedicated server with 512 RAM and 20 Go SSD to a VPN connection.

Comment: But maintaining a xmpp server is expensive to me.